Difference between `for item in list` and `for i in range(len(list))` when updating items in nested list
My understanding is that if I want to update the items of a list in place, this works,
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] += 1

and this doesn't,
l = [1, 2, 3]
for num in l:
    num += 1

because in the "for each" loop, in each iteration num creates a copy of each element in l.
But if I want to modify a nested list,
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l[i])):
        l[i][j] += 1

and
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for sublist in l:
    for i in range(len(sublist)):
        sublist[i] += 1

both work, and this doesn't work:
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for sublist in l:
    for num in sublist:
        num += 1

So now I am really confused, if the "for each" loop creates copies of the elements in l, then shouldn't the second one not work because sublist are copies of the list in l, then the next for loop modifies the elements in sublist instead of the lists in l, so l shouldn't change. But it did, can someone explain this to me?

num isn't mutable, so num += 1 is equivalent to num = num + 1. No copies involved, just local changes to the name num that don't affect the values in l at all.

The for loop is really irrelevant to the question. This is just about assigning a variable versus modifying a container object.


because in the "for each" loop, in each iteration num creates a copy of each element in l.

No, that is incorrect. A for-each loop doesn't copy any elements in the iterable implicitly. None of the iterators for the built-in types do that either. The reason is very simple.
This statement, an augmented assignment statement using a subscription assignment target:
l[i] += 1

mutates a list object (since l is a list object here).
But this statement:
num += 1

does not mutate an int object (num is an int object here). Assignment to a variable never mutates. Of course, int objects don't expose any mutator methods, they are immutable.
Assignment to a subscription,
my_object[item] = whatever

Will invoke the type's __setitem__, which will typically mutate the object (that's how built-in types, like list, work. Of course, you could implement a type with a __setitem__ that does whatever you want).

For the second example, what might make it more clear to the OP is showing it as: num = l[i]; num += 1, whereas the in-place l[i] += 1 assignment is more akin to num = l[i]; num += 1; l[i] = num or l[i] = l[i] + 1

This works:
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] += 1

Because you are incrementing l[i]. It's equivalent to:
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = l[i] + 1

This does not:
for num in l:
    num += 1

Because you are just incrementing a separate value. It's equivalent to:
for i in range(len(l)):
    num = l[i]
    num = num + 1

You probably expected that for num in l gave you reference num to each element of l. But you're really just getting the value of each element of l in order in num. Incrementing the value doesn't do anything to l or its contents.
What may be confusing is when the same happens with mutable objects. For example:
dicts = [{1: 2}, {1: 3}]
for d in dicts:
    d[1] += 1
print(dicts)

This does modify the dictionaries in the list, because the values in the list are the actual dictionaries, which can then be modified in the loop and since these dictionaries are also in the list, you get what you expect.
You can see it a bit more clearly if you unpack it in the same way:
for i in range(len(dicts)):
    d = dicts[i]
    d[1] = d[1] + 1

When you have something like x = 1; x = x + 1, you don't expect 1 to change, but you expect the sum to be assigned to x, so x gets a new value - it's not like "the 1 in x gets changed". Similarly, with d = dicts[i]; d[1] = d[1] + 1 the sum gets assigned to d[1], but that means d is changed, which is the ith dictionary in dicts. dicts doesn't get changed, it still has the same dictionary in the same spot.

you are getting a reference to the element in the list. But the object it is referencing is immutable.
